# Using df.drop(idx) results to Errorcode: Out of Memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

My original dataframe `df_clean` has 536000+ records and I want delete records based on certain conditions using grouppby and filter. Here is the code:

```
df_pairs = df_clean.groupby([df_clean.CustomerID, df_clean.StockCode, df_clean.Quantity.abs()]).filter(lambda x: (len(x.Quantity.abs()) % 2 == 0) and (x.Quantity.sum() == 0))
```

`len(df_pairs)` is 4016

Then I took the index:

```
 idx=df_pairs.index
```

And use drop function:

```
df_clean.drop(idx)
```

But this last code of dropping took too much time and in the end it's like it crashed and gave a whitepage showing Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. Error code: Out of Memory. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSrCX.png)

I have already tried reloading, shutting down my kernel and restarting my computer but I still get the same white page.

I also tried an alternative way using `.loc` and `~`

```
df_clean = df_clean.loc[~((df_clean.groupby([df_clean.CustomerID, df_clean.StockCode, df_clean.Quantity.abs()]).filter(lambda x: (len(x.Quantity.abs()) % 2 == 0) and (x.Quantity.sum() == 0))))]
```

But it gives me an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\MARTIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7792/227912236.py in <module>
----> 1 df_clean = df_clean.loc[~((df_clean.groupby([df_clean.CustomerID, df_clean.StockCode, df_clean.Quantity.abs()]).filter(lambda x: (len(x.Quantity.abs()) % 2 == 0) and (x.Quantity.sum() == 0))))]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __invert__(self)
   1530             return self
   1531 
-> 1532         new_data = self._mgr.apply(operator.invert)
   1533         return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="__invert__")
   1534 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    323             try:
    324                 if callable(f):
--> 325                     applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    326                 else:
    327                     applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in apply(self, func, **kwargs)
    379         """
    380         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
--> 381             result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
    382 
    383         return self._split_op_result(result)

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'DatetimeArray'
```

Please advise other alternative ways on how I can remove the records I filtered (stored in `df_pairs`). Any ideas or solutions would be appreciated.

**Note:** I cannot use `isin()` or `pd.concat` then `drop_duplicates()` because my dataset is a sales transactions history where each record is a line in an invoice. Something like this:

| InvoiceNo | StockCode | Description | Quantity | InvoiceDate | UnitPrice | CustomerID | TotalSales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 536365 | 85123A | WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER | 6 | 2018-11-29 08:26:00 | 2.55 | 17850 | 15.30 |
| 536365 | 71053 | WHITE METAL LANTERN | 6 | 2018-11-29 08:26:00 | 3.39 | 17850 | 20.34 |
| 536365 | 84406B | CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER | 8 | 2018-11-29 08:26:00 | 2.75 | 17850 | 22.00 |
| 536365 | 84029G | KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE | 6 | 2018-11-29 08:26:00 | 3.39 | 17850 | 20.34 |
| 536365 | 84029E | RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART. | 6 | 2018-11-29 08:26:00 | 3.39 | 17850 | 20.34 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using drop like that will return ANOTHER dataframe without those rows. You may want to try operating on the original dataframe so that a new one isn't made.

Instead of:

```
df = df.drop(idxs)
```

do:

```
df.drop(idxs, inplace=True)
```

You're nearly doubling the memory needed until the garbage collector claims the original.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I used. `df_clean.drop(idx)`

Comment: I think it is solved now.. I  used `df_clean = df_clean.drop(idx)` and put it in a separate cell.